# what is the result about the recursive Macro spread?

Tags: c++, c, macros

```
#include <iostream>
#define help(a) #a
#define xhelp(a) help(a)
#define glue(a,b) a##b
#define xglue(a,b) glue(a,b)
#define HIGHLOW "hello"
#define LOWLOW ",world" 
int main() 
{
              std::cout<<xhelp(xglue(HIGH,LOW))<<std::endl;
              return 0;
 }
```

here is my test code. I want to know the spread of the MACOR xglue(HIGH,LOW).

For me, i think the result is "hello"

but i learn from one website, the result is "hello, world".

I am really confused with it.

the result of my code is aslo "hello".

Is there anyone could help me with it?

I think the xgule(HIGH,LOW)=glue(HIGH,LOW)=HIGHLOW="hello"

THe website show that xglue(HIGH,LOW)=glue(HIGH,LOW",world")="hello, world"

Comment: result : `"\"hello\""`

Comment: result is `"hello"`. post the wesite link.

Comment: it's a chinese website. at the end of website       http://hi.baidu.com/feixue/item/b22cdca63f778417a9cfb729

Comment: website example `LOW LOW` not `LOWLOW`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no recursive macro.

Most work in the example is performed by the two preprocessor operators `#` and `##`.

`#` is a unary operator that turns its argument into a string literal.

`##` is a binary operator that pastes two tokens together to form one single token.

The easiest way to check what a given preprocessor code expands to is actually to run the preprocessor. The `g++` compiler has a `-E` option to do exactly that.

```
# Assuming your file is saved as code.cpp
$ g++ -E code.cpp
... lots of output ...
int main()
{
    std::cout<<"\"hello\""<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```